# Vectorization in loops

Tags: c++, llvm, vectorization

I have the two below loops:

```
For i=1…n
    a[i] = a[i+1] + 1

For i=1…n
    b[i] = b[i-1] + 1
```

Now considering that both the arrays are initialised, which of them can be vectorized? 
Also does the answer change if the arrays are not initialised because if the values are not initialized then in the first loop a[i+1] is needed before its computed.

edit1: The loops here are trying to copy 4 bytes at a time, if I want to copy 16 bytes at a time can it be done? Are there any restraint for it?

Comment: This isn't c++ code, whatever you're asking about.

Comment: For the record are you trying to determine what a compiler will do or why it will do that because the latter is a bit of a homework question.

Comment: If you look at the auto vectorization article it has options for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
void test2(int* A, int Length){
for (int i = 0; i+1 < Length; i++) {
      A[i] = A[i+1] + 1;
    }
}

void test3(int* A, int Length){
for (int i = 1; i < Length; i++) {
      A[i] = A[i-1] + 1;
    }
}
```

Gives the result

```
vector.cpp:12:14: remark: vectorized loop (vectorization width: 4, interleaved count: 2) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]
      A[i] = A[i+1] + 1;
             ^
vector.cpp:18:17: remark: vectorized loop (vectorization width: 4, interleaved count: 2) [-Rpass=loop-vectorize]
      A[i] = A[i-1] + 1;
```

with this command line
`clang++-3.8 -O3 -Rpass=loop-vectorize vector.cpp`
So according to clang they both are automatically on O3

start here [Auto-Vectorization](http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.1/docs/Vectorizers.html)

Edit: Even better [here](http://blog.llvm.org/2014/11/loop-vectorization-diagnostics-and.html) is a blog post with examples